# How can I fix this problems heroku web

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'am new at this so please help me.

2020-10-01T09:37:17.833139+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-10-01T09:37:23.403282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2020-10-01T09:37:25.308007+00:00 app[web.1]: Node LTS version v10.22.1 is supported
2020-10-01T09:37:25.310036+00:00 app[web.1]: Parsing config URL from IMPORT_CONFIG failed
2020-10-01T09:37:25.481614+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting up new connection to MongoDB
2020-10-01T09:37:25.528135+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
2020-10-01T09:37:25.974982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-10-01T09:37:26.005597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-01T09:37:34.113589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=reineholmensocker.herokuapp.com request_id=852dd0cf-cd9d-43ba-9f34-a2dd19d4423a fwd="2.67.142.46" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-01T09:37:34.407323+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=reineholmensocker.herokuapp.com request_id=6c611add-042e-48a3-a996-fa22cf4e98bd fwd="2.67.142.46" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

Please read your error logs before posting them, also make sure to put them in codeblocks to make it readable.

As the error states, the failure is in the mongodb connection.
Initialize the mongodb connection after this:

```
mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);
```